# Bad kernel, how to fix?

Tags: debian, vps

I am told by my VPS hosting service that I have a bad kernel that is not allowing things to load.

They do not provide software support so they won't fix it. How may I fix it? It is Linux Debian7-64 3.2.0-4-amd64

Please help, because right now every port is blocked.

Comment: Why does your VHSP say the kernel is "bad"? You need to get a reason from them.

Comment: This was their response
This seems to be in fact a problem with the VPS's kernel. Have you recently done any changes to it? maybe a distribution upgrade? This normally happens when something messes with the kernel's default configuration.

Answer (score 0):

1. Start backing up everything, files, DB's

If I would be you would simply reinstall VPS and restore everything back.

2. Check firewall settings, that may be firewall blocking your ports

It depends what kind of VPS is there, for instance Virtuozzo VPS boxes are altered, Including Kernel, they come as templates, and correcting them probably won't be possible, check what is your VPS build on.

Do this steps first, and if for some reason you will still decide to fix it, give us more information...